# Copy file in server 2008

Tags: batch-file, server, xcopy, user-profile

I want to write `*.bat` file to copy but it's not working:

```
-Source:  (Ex)  \\192.168.1.100\Data\ exception.sites (File is exception.sites)
-Destination:  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security (%USERPROFILE%\ is C:\user\acc logon domain)

set source=\\192.168.1.100\Data\exception.sites\ set destination=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote your arguments

```
set "source=\\192.168.1.100\Data\exception.sites\"
set "destination=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\"
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
```

Note that the quotes come before the variable name.